# Why I am getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in loading applicationContext in JBoss7.1.EAP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jboss

I am getting the following error, when I am trying to deploy an ear into dev server where its published to JBoss7.1.EAP. The error is coming at the start of the server.
This error is not coming when I am trying to deploy in local JBOSS server.
This is coming when I am trying to deploy to remote server.

The application is in Spring5 Hibernate, the ear contains a war file and an ejb jar .

```
2019-05-30 18:31:24,597 INFO [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 185) Shutting down ExecutorService taskExecutor
2019-05-30 18:31:24,617 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 185) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name excleXMLRegistrant defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader.hasClassAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1231)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1130)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:205)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:174)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:239)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:99)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader.hasClassAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:252)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.<init>(RegistryInfoImpl.java:103)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:417)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:387)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:465)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1174)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:286)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:137)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:108)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:286)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:412)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:375)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:279)
at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.utilities.XmlService.fromXML(XmlService.java:106)
at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.utilities.ExpressionRunner.getJaxBObject(ExpressionRunner.java:430)
at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.registrant.ExcleXMLRegistrant.<clinit>(ExcleXMLRegistrant.java:115)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1223)
... 33 more
```

The war file contains the relevant jars in WEB-INF/lib folder

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have two versions of jaxb-impl in your WEB-INF folder. One version is 2.0.5 and another version is 2.2.7. You need to remove the older version from your dependencies.

Also you have jaxb-api-2.1 in your dependencies.You need 2.2 version.

All in all looking through the contents of your WEB-INF lib you have a lot of libraries which are duplicated with different version. You need to do some clean up I believe.

Comment: True..I will do it..I can see hasClassAnnotation() method is present in jaxb-core2.2.7..but let me clear one of the version and try to deploy

Comment: @sromit you don't have control  over the order in which the dependencies are loaded inside the WEB-INF/lib it is very possible that the older jar is loaded before the newer one.

Comment: Once i removed the older version...the error is gone now in deployment..Thanx for the pointer :)